# Input button position is off in Chrome?

Tags: css, forms, button, input, alignment

The input button for this email subscription form is aligned correctly with the input field when I open the page in Firefox, but in Chrome it looks a bit off.

Would someone help me figure out how to make it line up correctly in Chrome? Thank you so much!

**The html code:**

```
<div id="socialmedia">

    <form action="********/account.php" name="digiSHOP" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="m" value="subscribe" />

        <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true" />

        <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="a6887a2c4d7909f10a4e01778cdd4b02" />

        <input type="hidden" name="mailingListId" value="1" />

        <div class="form-label" >
            <div class="nicelabel" >
                <img border="0" src="updateme.gif" width="132" height="30"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="niceform" >
                <input align="left" type="text" value=" your email" name="email" style="width:150px; height:24px; maxlength="80" value="" size="20" />
                <input class="edit-button" type="submit" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS style:**

```
#socialmedia{
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}

.form-label {
    float: left;
    width: 400px; height: 28px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.nicelabel { float: left; text-align:left; width:132px; }

.niceform { float: left; text-align:right; width:230px; }

input, textarea {margin-left: 0px; }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistencies like these exist amongst different browsers. There are two ways you can tackle this issue:

Using absolute positioning

HTML

```
<form class="contact-form">
    email id <input type="text"/><input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
form.contact-form{
    position:relative;
}

form.contact-form input[type=text]{
    position:aboslute;
    top:0;
}

form.contact-form input[type=submit]{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

This method pushed the elements of the form right to the top, which in
turn assures alignment. js fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/xcpSg/

Using Tables
Tables can do you the job too. Facebook uses
this method for the login form at the top of their home page.

Comment: `position:absolute;` spelling mistake in your fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting tables, THAT fixed the problem while the CSS solution doesn't have any effect. Still I feel that must be a way in CSS to fix this?

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean non-tables when you say CSS, yes there are many ways you can do it with CSS, it requires basic knowledge on positioning, both absolute and/or relative. In most cases the final product will be the same, and it depends entirely upon you as the coder about which method to opt for.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a small error with your code itself

`<img border="0" src="updateme.gif" width="132" height="30"></a>`

Here you are giving `closing anchor tag` without `<a>` anywhere
and you are also not closing `img` tag like below.

`<img border="0" src="updateme.gif" width="132" height="30"/>`

Check by correcting these things.

Comment: Oops! Thank you for catching that! (Just for clarification, turned out the error had no effect on the problem at hand.)